# How to implement a CursorLoader for Android API level <11

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursorloader

I have an application with many list activities (5-6 of them), and all of them have custom cursor adapters, from my own ContentProvider(2), sitting on an Sqlite database(2).

Now the problem, I want to implement CursorLoader (or like) class to load the cursors on background thread, below API level < 11, preferably 6 to 9..

I also want to show a ProgressSpinner, while the list is loading.

What to do, best, AsynTask? Thread? or write my own CursorLoader for <11, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) (Part of the SDK). It contains the Loader-Framework for Android API Level >= 4.