# How to get LoaderManager in a ListActivity

Tags: android, android-loadermanager

I am using compatibility package for implementing CursorLoader in API level < 11
As per the [doc](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Downloading) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7833860/implementation-of-cursorloader-for-api-level-11/7834023#7834023) and this wonderful [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/), I have imported the support packages and implemented the [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html), but next I have to call:

```
getSupportLoaderManager()
```

and for that one has to extend FragmentActivity, and then call from Activity Context, but I have already extended ListActivity, and want to make a static call to get LoaderManager, like this:

```
    FragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager()
```

Apparently, this is a way to get [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) < 11, that's what the doc says:

> To manage your fragments and loaders, you must use the methods FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() and FragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager() (instead of the getFragmentManager() and getLoaderManager() methods).

But it is giving this compile time error:

```
Cannot make a static call to a non-static method
```

[Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-eksempler/source/browse/trunk/Android30Elementer/src/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java?r=50) for FragmentActivity, getSupportLoaderManager() is not static here, that explains the error, but why is the Doc showing a static call...i am confused now...

Please help!

Comment: you can't do it, doc not showing static call it just means that you should call this method within class which extends FragmentActivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6497121/399105

Answer (score 11):

You can only use the `Loader` framework from the Android Compatibility Library if you extend `FragmentActivity`. Consider converting your `ListActivity` into a `ListFragment` and a `FragmentActivity`.